# Android - using buttons from XML layout in a service.class

Tags: android, button, service

I'm developing an app which is started from a service. Since there is a 5 second delay before the activity is recreated after using HOME button, I started to recreate my app without activity as a GUI. I'm struggling hard to get my buttons from the XML layout to work, stupid me.

I can use a button which is created on the fly, but I need to use all buttons I defined in the layout XML.

This is how it looks now:

```
// display the layout to screen

LayoutInflater inflater = (LayoutInflater) getSystemService(LAYOUT_INFLATER_SERVICE);
View myView = inflater.inflate(R.layout.xmllayout, null);     
wm.addView(myView, params); 


// tried to use getIdentifier - log shows the button id number

final int id = getResources().getIdentifier("btn1", "id", getPackageName());
final ImageButton btn1 = (ImageButton) findViewById(id);           

Log.i(TAG, "Found Button ID:" + getResources().getIdentifier("btn1", "id", getPackageName()));


// how i define the button in a activity
// ImageButton btn1 = (ImageButton) myView.findViewById(btn1);           

btn1.setOnClickListener(new ImageButton.OnClickListener()
{
              @Override
              public void onClick(View arg0)
              {
                  //Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(), "Starting ", Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
              }
            });
```

`myView.findViewById(btn1);` returns error:

```
The method findViewById(int) is undefined for the type
```

Any help welcome about how I can use the buttons from my XML layout :)

Comment: error arise while calling 'myView.findViewById' or 'findViewById' ??

Comment: Try to use myView.findViewById(), since `Service` is not an `Activity`, you cannot call this method directly

Comment: you have to pass id in findviewbyid method not a view object, so try myView.findViewById(id);

Answer (score 2):

Have u tried

`myView.findViewById(R.id.buttonId)` ???

buttonId = your button id defined in xml file

```
<ImageButton
  android:id="@+id/buttonId" />
```

Comment: myView.findViewById(R.id.buttonId) works like a charm, how could i be that blind, thanks.